# JQuery Validation Validating two fields Error

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery Validation to try to validate two input fields in my form. The problem that I am coming across is that it does not matter which one I have as the first one, the secondary one is never called with validation unless the field is dynamically filled in by a value entered in earlier in the form. Here are two sections that I am having a problem with:

```
               <div class="form-panel">
                <div class="row collapse">
                    <div class="medium-3 columns">
                        <label for="selectFinish" class="inline show-for-medium-up"> Style</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-9 columns">
                        <select name="Pri-CompID" id="selectFinish" class="priceCalc required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                            <option value="">Select a size before proceeding.</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-panel">
                <div class="row collapse">
                    <div class="medium-3 columns">
                        <label for="selectFastener" class="inline show-for-medium-up"> Fastener</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-9 columns">
                        <select name="Pri-CompID" id="selectFastener" class="priceCalc required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                            <option value="">Select a size before proceeding.</option>
                        </select>
                        <div id="punchSlot"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: please add all your html and jquery/javascript code in order to identify the issue.

Comment: I am using the JQuery Validation Plugin and the above code is wrapped in a form.

Comment: where do you initialize the validate plugin ?

Comment: At the bottom of my page after page loads.

Comment: post your javascript code

Comment: The page that has the issue is http://www.nametag.com/name-tags/custom-name-tags-metal.php